# CROSS APPLY date table onto some data - why the duplication

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008-r2

This is the data:

```
SELECT X.*
INTO   #X
FROM   (
       VALUES
       ('A',CAST('01 Feb 2013' AS DATETIME)),
       ('B','01 Mar 2013'),
       ('C','01 Sep 2013')
       ) X(Player,Mth)
```

We have a pretty standard factory `DimDate` table in our warehouse.

If I do the following to find the number of days it works fine:

```
SELECT Player,Mth,
    numDays_mth = COUNT(XXX.DateKey),
FROM #X A
    CROSS APPLY 
    (
    SELECT DateKey 
    FROM WHData.dbo.vw_DimDate DT 
    WHERE DT.DayMarker >= A.Mth 
        AND DT.DayMarker < DATEADD(MONTH, 1, A.Mth)
    ) XXX
```

Also for the number of days from the previous month things work fine:

```
SELECT Player,Mth,
    numDays_prevMth = COUNT(YYY.DateKey)     
FROM #X A
    CROSS APPLY 
    (
    SELECT DateKey 
    FROM WHData.dbo.vw_DimDate DTT 
    WHERE DTT.DayMarker >= DATEADD(MONTH, -1, A.Mth) 
    AND DTT.DayMarker < A.Mth
    ) YYY
```

If I combine the two then there are problems:

```
SELECT Player,Mth,
    numDays_mth = COUNT(XXX.DateKey),
    numDays_prevMth = COUNT(YYY.DateKey)    
FROM #X A
     CROSS APPLY 
     (
     SELECT DateKey 
     FROM WHData.dbo.vw_DimDate DT 
     WHERE DT.DayMarker >= A.Mth 
         AND DT.DayMarker < DATEADD(MONTH, 1, A.Mth)
     ) XXX
    CROSS APPLY 
    (
    SELECT DateKey 
    FROM WHData.dbo.vw_DimDate DTT 
    WHERE DTT.DayMarker >= DATEADD(MONTH, -1, A.Mth) 
    AND DTT.DayMarker < A.Mth
    ) YYY
```

**I realise there are plenty of other ways of getting these day counts** but I'm trying to understand the workings of the `APPLY` operator as much as anything.

How do I keep using `APPLY` twice and stop the duplication of data?

---

**note**

Changing the `SELECT` clause to the following works on this trivial example but has a massive impact on performance for a production script:

```
SELECT Player,Mth,
    numDays_mth = COUNT(DISTINCT XXX.DateKey),
    numDays_prevMth = COUNT(DISTINCT YYY.DateKey)
```

Comment: "How do I keep using `APPLY` twice and stop the apparent duplication of data?" - is a bit of the wrong sort of question to ask - you get the duplication *because* you're `APPLY`ing twice - the first time, you expand the number of rows by some factor. That *expanded* set of rows is then used as the *input* for the second `APPLY`.

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever - just took out the work "apparent". Could I drop one of the `APPLY`s and somehow do both counts from one `APPLY`? Maybe I'm just abusing `APPLY` and should go back to something more standard?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would move the `COUNT`s inside of the `CROSS APPLY` so that each one only produces one row of output for each input row on the [left hand side](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms175156%28v=sql.105%29.aspx). That way you avoid creating additional rows to act as input to the second (or subsequent) `APPLY`:

```
SELECT Player,Mth,
    numDays_mth = XXX.Cnt,
    numDays_prevMth = YYY.Cnt   
FROM #X A
     CROSS APPLY 
     (
     SELECT COUNT(DateKey) 
     FROM WHData.dbo.vw_DimDate DT 
     WHERE DT.DayMarker >= A.Mth 
         AND DT.DayMarker < DATEADD(MONTH, 1, A.Mth)
     ) XXX (Cnt)
    CROSS APPLY 
    (
    SELECT COUNT(DateKey)
    FROM WHData.dbo.vw_DimDate DTT 
    WHERE DTT.DayMarker >= DATEADD(MONTH, -1, A.Mth) 
    AND DTT.DayMarker < A.Mth
    ) YYY (Cnt)
```

Comment: Yes, just cross-apply one row for each outer row. This is a good practice anyway. Aggregate inside the apply/join source.

Comment: @whytheq - and in answer to your deleted comment - no this wasn't tested as shown (the general form was) because you gave no sample data and expected results. If you don't provide those on an SQL question, you're unlikely to get tested results. Ideally, the sample data should be `INSERT` statements - or you can provide an [sqlfiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/)

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever I deleted the comment because I thought there was an error - but there wasn't (I shouldn't have been an unbeliever): I just copied your `FROM` clause and my result just showed 1's. `sqlfiddle` is great, but might not always be around so including code to create the sample data is better: I usually use `INSERT` but just used `VALUES` for a change and assumed that most readers will have a `Date` table - surely a reasonable assumption?